# Translating "Please enter your email below and we'll send you confirmation link for it."

Tags: magento-1.8, localisation

I'm trying to translate the string
"Please enter your email below and we'll send you confirmation link for it."

I've read the article [here](http://www.magegyver.de/translating-please-enter-your-email-below-and-well-send-you-confirmation-link-for-it-in-register-form/) and adding "\" to confirmation.phtml works indeed.

```
<?php echo $this->__('Please enter your email below and we\\\'ll send 
you confirmation link for it.') ?>
```

What I don't understand is why with the second option in the article one has to create a new translation file.
I've tried modifying MageCustomer.csv directly but it doesn't seems to work.
Why correcting the MageCustomer.csv by deleting the "\" doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't update directly the `Mage_Customer.csv`because on the day you make a Magento upgrade you will lose all your changes.
2. Add your custom translations in **local**: `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/locale/{lang_ISO}/translate.csv` then put your changes inside.
3. You can also use the simply one [Inline translation](http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/) the translations are stored in the `core_translate` **database** table.

Comment: As I said, changing the confirmation.phtml work, changing the MageCustomer.csv doesn't. I was wondering, why is so?
Even adding the string to translate.csv doesn't seem to work...